# Obtaining and defining a `ratetable` from a Cox P-H model for use in `survexp`

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm currently trying to make some simple models of client lifetime value. I'm using the following simplified formula for some survival analysis on client values

```
fit1 <- coxph( Surv(Start, Start + Time, Death) ~ Service, survData)
```

I can call `basehaz` on `fit1` and obtain the following cumulative hazard table (this is just the head of the table.

`haztable <- basehaz(fit1)`

```
        hazard time
1  0.01091445    2
2  0.04350026    3
3  0.07699729    4
4  0.12015616    5
5  0.16105550    6
6  0.19153200    7
7  0.22920218    9
```

What I would like to do now is to use this data and hazard rate information to calculate the expected survival times, but I'm running into errors.

`survexp(fit1, survData, ratetable=haztable)` for example gets me the `Invalid rate table` error. The default ratetable seems to be taken from the US census data table. I'm unclear as to how to proceed to define my own and call it.

Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function "survexp" provides survival probabilities at different time points. In your example, you could obtain them using

```
survexp(~Service, ratetable=fit1, data = survData)
```

Since you are interested in expected survival times (rather than survival probabilities at different time points), you should follow the discussion in [Prediction in Cox regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36015/prediction-in-cox-regression) and e.g. get group medians by calling

```
 survfit(fit1, newdata = survData)
```

Comment: Ok, that's great answer does what I asked and a bit more. I suspect I will award you the loot, but I'll just wait a few hours to see if anyone else surpasses this (I doubt it).